# Multi-output regression model always returns the same value for a batch in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, regression

I have a multi-layer perceptron for a multi-output regression problem which predicts 14 continuous values. The following is the code snippet for the same:

```
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 1000
batch_size = 500

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 32 
n_hidden_2 = 200 
n_hidden_3 = 200
n_hidden_4 = 256
n_input = 14
n_classes = 14

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input],name="x")
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'h4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4, n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)

    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(layer_4)

    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer   

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred-y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Run the graph in the session 
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(init)
      for epoch in range(training_epochs):
            avg_cost = 0.
            total_batch = int(total_len/batch_size)
            for i in range(total_batch-1):
                batch_x = X_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
                batch_y = Y_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
                _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                avg_cost += c / total_batch
```

OUTPUT:

```
x_batch_data:
[  1.77560000e+04   4.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+00 ...,   1.00000000e+00
5.61000000e+02   1.00000000e+00]
[  1.34310000e+04   4.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+00 ...,   1.00000000e+00
5.61000000e+02   1.00000000e+00]
[  2.98800000e+03   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 ...,   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]

y_batch_data:
[[  4.19700000e-01   1.04298450e+02   1.50000000e+02 ...,   2.75250000e-01
1.02000000e-01   7.28565000e+00]
[  5.59600000e-01   1.39064600e+02   2.00000000e+02 ...,   3.67000000e-01
1.36000000e-01   9.71420000e+00]
[  2.79800000e-01   6.95323000e+01   1.00000000e+02 ...,   1.83500000e-01
6.80000000e-02   4.85710000e+00]

Prediction: 
[[   0.85085869   90.53585815  130.17015076 ...,    0.62335277
 0.26637274    5.52062225]
[   0.85085869   90.53585815  130.17015076 ...,    0.62335277
 0.26637274    5.52062225]
[   0.85085869   90.53585815  130.17015076 ...,    0.62335277
 0.26637274    5.52062225]
```

The predicted value is always same despite different input values. Can someone point out what could be the reason behind this?

P.S Similar questions referred to: [tensorflow deep neural network for regression always predict same results in one batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399609/tensorflow-deep-neural-network-for-regression-always-predict-same-results-in-one#comment80414265_38399609)

Approaches tried:
1. Gradually reduced the learning rate from 0.1 to 0.0001
2. Tried other optimizer algorithms
3. Changed the network architecture (number of hidden nodes and layers and activation functions)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `X_train` and `Y_train`?

Comment: The dimension of X_train and Y_train is (40000, 12) and (40000, 19) respectively

Comment: I ran your code and did not get the same estimated value each epoch... What is `total_len` defined as?

Comment: How many epochs did you run? I get unique results until 5 epochs but after that the values remain the same for the further epochs

Comment: The total length is `X_train.shape[0]` which in this case is 40000

Comment: I don't have your data, so I generated some with `X_train = np.random.random(1000).reshape(200,5); Y_train = np.random.random(200*19).reshape(200,19)`. I ran for 50 epochs and values were still unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156697/discussion-between-brenden-petersen-and-vasanti).

Comment: Why don't you call the init?

Comment: I slightly modified your code by just adding `X_train = np.random.random(40000*14).reshape(40000, 14); Y_train = np.random.random(40000*14).reshape(40000, 14)`, `ix = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=())` and `sess.run(init)` at appropriate places. I ran for 100 epochs but I still observed different predicted values. Is there some way to reproducing your problem?

Comment: I also ran with random data and observed different predicted values. Is there anyway we can get hold of your data ?

Comment: I guess it may be dying relu, I've used this and faced similar values. maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

The problems seem to be:

- you didn't call tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
- the batches aren't selected randomly (INDEXES never gets referenced), so you might be feeding the same batch each time
- and the weights never change (you didn't fetch 'optimizer' in sess.run().)

The predictions will remain the same if the weights stay the same and the batch inputs remain the same. Hopefully that helps to fix it.

Comment: My apologies for not editing the question sooner. The init method is run inside the session and also the data for every batch is different. I still face the same issue. P.S: I have edited the question with a new batch generation process.

Comment: @Vasanti me too, but I don't have that much reputation to make a new bounty :) I don't know how to solve the issue.